# Analytics event to fire without click

Tags: events, google-analytics

I have a web article where I want to know how many users are getting to a particular section. There is no click event associated with this section or reaching it, the user simply scrolls down the page.

How can I setup an event for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, replacing *my-element* with the id of your section.

```js
var scrollTop     = $(window).scrollTop(),
    elementOffset = $('#my-element').offset().top,
    distance      = (elementOffset - scrollTop),
    hasEventBeenSent = false;

function checkScrollDepth() {
  if (!hasEventBeenSent) {
    var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPos >= distance) {
      sendScrollEvent();
    }
  }
}

function sendScrollEvent() {
  ga('send', 'event', 'Scroll Event', 'event_action', 'event_label');
  hasEventBeenSent = true;
}

$(window).on('scroll', checkScrollDepth);
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't' seem to be working for me on my webpage. 

I am using the google events Event Tracking Tracker in chrome. The click events are firing fine but this code isn't. 

Any reasons you can think of for this? It's for a wordpress site. I've tried adding in the JS in a script tag before and after the html, and also in the custom script field. No luck

Comment: Can you share the URL of the page that you're trying to get the event to fire on?  Also, please include the element that you want to be in view when the event fires.

Comment: This is the page: https://www.trustedclothes.com/blog/2017/01/03/start-vegan-lifestyle-personal-experience-advices/?preview_id=59251&preview_nonce=6e0ccde444&post_format=standard&_thumbnail_id=59252&preview=true

The element is the text 'Related Articles'

Comment: Brian can you get anything from that url?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, but it looks like you have a javascript error on that page that is preventing jQuery from loading. See [screenshot](https://ibb.co/duxEKQ)